# Swift How can i take data from custom uicollectionviewcell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a form page like below image. I should take value from this form. I have a custom collection view from the bottom. I should take textfield value from the cell. how can I do that?

I use the picker view in those cells. Can you show a little example for me?

[image: this]

Comment: Show what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question: "I should take textfield value from the cell. how can I do that?"

Answer: You shouldn't do that.

View objects are for displaying information to the user and for collecting input, not for storing data.

This is especially important for `UICollectionView`s and `UITableView`s, since both of those create and recycle cells as needed as the user scrolls.

You should design your collection view to have a data model object (typically an array of structs, or an array of arrays for data in rows and columns).

As the user enters data into your text fields and taps return, you should collect the changed values and save them to your data model. Then your data model is always up-to-date and if you need to fetch the value for a specific IndexPath you just look up the data in the model.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the indexPath for your cell, its easy like:

```
 let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
 let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? GuestDataCell
 let value = cell?.txtDataValue.text
```

**EDIT after comments**:

Not best practice, but if you need:

```
var i = 0
var numberOfCells = 4
var values: [String]!

while i < numberOfCells {
   let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
   let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? GuestDataCell
   let value = cell?.txtDataValue.text
   values.append(value)
   i += 1
}
```

But I dont really recommend you to write like this. Read please Duncan's answer.

Comment: This solution is working. But "item: index" is not working. When i add "0 or 1" it's working.

Comment: Because ‘index’ is just a variable for your item. It can be any integer

Comment: I try array but its not working. I have four cells. how can i get data from each?

Comment: I try your code but index give me error: "Cannot convert value of type '(Any) -> Int' to expected argument type 'Int'". By the way i use this code in my button function.
@objc func handleSaveButton() { }